# how to manual link npm package 'react native reanimated'

Tags: android, react-native, npm, manual, npm-link

Can anyone please tell me how to manual link

> react-native-reanimated

because the automatic cli linking not working and crashing react native app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Android,Add the following lines to android/settings.gradle

`include ':react-native-reanimated'
project(':react-native-reanimated').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android')`

Add the compile line to the dependencies in android/app/build.gradle

`implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')`

the import and link the package in MainApplication.java

`import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage;`

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
         new ReanimatedPackage(), );// <-- add this line
}
}
```

in android/build.gradle

```
ext {
compileSdkVersion           = 25
targetSdkVersion            = 25
buildToolsVersion           = "25.0.2"
googlePlayServicesVersion   = "12.0.1"
supportLibVersion           = "27.0.0"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay...... But i got this error :-A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> Cannot get property 'supportLibVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

Comment: add this code in you android/build.gradle:  `ext {
    compileSdkVersion           = 25
    targetSdkVersion            = 25
    buildToolsVersion           = "25.0.2"
    googlePlayServicesVersion   = "12.0.1"
    supportLibVersion           = "27.0.0"
}`